# Join adjacent polygons based on aspect values only when "look each other"

Tags: qgis, r, merge, aspect

I have a map with polygons that represent the average of aspect for a certain slope of a mountain region. I'm looking for a way to merge only adjacent polygons that "look to each other", depending on the aspect values. In practice I would like to merge polygons with similar exposition (i.e NE/N, SE/S) but only when the slope look to each others, otherwise keep them separate.

I reclassify the raster of the aspects in 8 classes (1=N, 2=NE, 3=E, 4=SE, 5=S, 6=SW, 7=W, 8=NW), then I polygonize the raster but I can not find a way to produce the result, the closest solution is this: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/185569/how-to-check-if-two-normals-directions-look-at-each-other

but until now I did not manage to apply it within QGIS or R.

Here you can find some data for testing (polygons and raster of aspect): [data for testing](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/4a2b7cc1b7d02241887a856d4cbae61320220309112832/0b222c5366256367c9f5a3f1640bd6d020220309112919/c88f70)

and an example of the input and the output desired.

First image are the polygons reclassify depending on aspects values, second what I mean for polygons that look each to other (i.e. 2 vs 3 or 4 vs 5 are looking to each other, 1 vs 7 or 6 vs 9 not). Third the result after the merging step that I would like to get.

[image]

Comment: I don't know why you've rasterized the polygons. If you keep the polygons, then construct the adjacency graph (spdep package) then its a graph theory problem to find the minimal number of subgraphs such that all adjacencies are 0 or 1, and you can recode from 0 to 7 and use mod-8 arithmetic to do that. Throw some polygon data at us and we might have a go...

Comment: I add the link with the data. I did not rasterized the polygons, I polygonized the raster of the aspects. I will check the package you suggested.

Comment: First you should make your goal cleaner conceptually, for instance, 2 looks to 3, 4 and 6, should we merge them all together? Furthermore, 5 would match with 4 too. So would you expect to have several merged polygons, like 2 with 4 in one, and 2 with 3? You may define the "look to each other" mathematically as a subtraction of the angles that approximates 180, (facing west is 270, minus 90 which is east, e.g.)

Comment: The merge procedure should be done only between adjacent polygons that "look each other" and for  adjacent I mean every  polygon that have a boundary in common. So yes, 2,3,4,5 and 6 at the end of the elaboration should become one unic polygon

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Please decide which of QGIS and R you wish to ask about within this question so that it and its answers can be focused on what you have tried and where you are stuck.  If it's R then please include your code attempt.